# The existence of solutions of a system of indeterminate equations

Tags: number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer satisfying $\dfrac{m(m+1)}{4}\in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that there exists a positive integer $t$ and $t$ positive integers $m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_t$ such that $$\begin{cases} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{t}m_k=m\\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{t}\dfrac{m_k(m_k+1)}{2}=\dfrac{m(m+1)}{4} \end{cases}.$$
P.S. This question comes from Problem F in The 2022 ICPC Asia Shenyang Regional Contest (https://codeforces.com/gym/104160/problem/F). One of the key steps in this problem is to find a set of solutions to the above indeterminate equations. And I noticed that $\dfrac{m(m+1)}{4}$ cannot be arbitrarily replaced by other positive integers, which may make the proposition no longer true.